# Acquire a user's email address?

Tags: windows, email

Is there a way to get the user's email address from within Windows via Win32 or .NET?  Is there a registry key or API that contains this information?

EDIT: I have an application that emails my company if our application fails and I wanted to get a return email address so that we could respond that individual that experienced the crash.  I'm currently getting the username, but that may not match the email name.  Obviously I can get the user to enter his email address, but the interface would be a little friendlier if I could at least attempt to acquire the email address and have the user verify that the return email address is correct.

Comment: Which one?  I have at least six, maybe more.

Comment: I don't know why this is getting downvoted. I can think of perfectly valid and useful reasons for doing this (auto form-filling, for instance). Of course there are also many invalid reasons.

Comment: +1 for drive-by downvoters. How is this question "unhelpful"?

Comment: It's unhelpful because the OS doesn't store that information.

Comment: Just because the answer is "No, there is no way to do that" doesn't mean it's a bad question.  That can be useful information to somebody else wondering the same thing.

Comment: Even if it was possible, it is just plain bad manners to go snooping around a clients rig looking their email addresses.  If the real purpose of needing the email is as you stated above, the user is not going to mind entering it once when they first install your app.  Be honest, not sneaky/evil.

Comment: -1 for most of the above reasons.  There are answers to this question, but no responsible or non-condemnation-worthy reason to ask.

Comment: Disagree strongly with Sparr. And it turns out that in Windows 8, the answer to this question will become Yes (at least for Microsoft trusted apps) because signing in with an email address is now part of a Windows 8 installation.  The OP stated he is trying to be helpful (save a user typing, if possible, something they may already have input somewhere.)

Answer (score 5):

The only way I can think that this would make sense is in a Windows Active Directory environment. In this case you can query AD and see if there's an email address associated with the user's account. This will definitely work with MS Exchange and may also work with other enterprise email systems. For .Net you can use the classes in the [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace. For Win32 you can use the [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772218(VS.85).aspx) API. You will have to read up on AD and create a suitable query to match your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Have you saved your e-mail address somewhere in the system? There is no standard place to look for. I always depends on the applications the user uses (Outlook, Outlook Express, TuhunderBird).

The best way to get the users e-mail address is to ask him.

Answer (score 3):

Let me answer you by asking you this: Did you ever enter your email address when installing windows?

Comment: No, of course not.  But you do enter it when you setup your Outlook and Thunderbird accounts.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `NameUserPrincipal` constant from the [`EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enumeration with the [`GetUserNameEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724435%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

> NameUserPrincipal
>   The user principal name (for example, someone@example.com).

But I would only recommend using this as a pre-filled address in a prompt to the user.

There is more than a good chance it will fail with `GetLastError` of `ERROR_NONE_MAPPED` though if the info is not available.

Answer (score 2):

Windows stores used email accounts in the "`UserExtendedProperties`" key in

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL
```

So you can get the email accounts using the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

#define MAX_KEY_LENGTH 255
#define MAX_VALUE_NAME 16383

void GetDefaultEmailAddress()
{
    HKEY key;
    TCHAR    achKey[MAX_KEY_LENGTH];   // buffer for subkey name
    DWORD    cbName;                   // size of name string 
    TCHAR    achClass[MAX_PATH] = TEXT("");  // buffer for class name 
    DWORD    cchClassName = MAX_PATH;  // size of class string 
    DWORD    cSubKeys = 0;               // number of subkeys 
    DWORD    cbMaxSubKey;              // longest subkey size 
    DWORD    cchMaxClass;              // longest class string 
    DWORD    cValues;              // number of values for key 
    DWORD    cchMaxValue;          // longest value name 
    DWORD    cbMaxValueData;       // longest value data 
    DWORD    cbSecurityDescriptor; // size of security descriptor 
    FILETIME ftLastWriteTime;      // last write time 

    DWORD i, retCode;

    TCHAR  achValue[MAX_VALUE_NAME];
    DWORD cchValue = MAX_VALUE_NAME;

    if (RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\IdentityCRL\\UserExtendedProperties", NULL, KEY_READ, &key) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        // Get the class name and the value count. 
        retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(
            key,                    // key handle 
            achClass,                // buffer for class name 
            &cchClassName,           // size of class string 
            NULL,                    // reserved 
            &cSubKeys,               // number of subkeys 
            &cbMaxSubKey,            // longest subkey size 
            &cchMaxClass,            // longest class string 
            &cValues,                // number of values for this key 
            &cchMaxValue,            // longest value name 
            &cbMaxValueData,         // longest value data 
            &cbSecurityDescriptor,   // security descriptor 
            &ftLastWriteTime);       // last write time 

        // Enumerate the email accounts subkeys, until RegEnumKeyEx fails.

        if (cSubKeys)
        {
            wprintf(TEXT("\nNumber of email accounts used: %d\n"), cSubKeys);

            for (i = 0; i < cSubKeys; i++)
            {
                cbName = MAX_KEY_LENGTH;
                retCode = RegEnumKeyEx(key, i,
                    achKey,
                    &cbName,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    NULL,
                    &ftLastWriteTime);
                if (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
                {
                    wprintf(TEXT("(%d) %s\n"), i + 1, achKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When it comes to desktop applications used for email (i.e. MAPI clients) the place to look in order to enumerate these clients, is the `Software\Clients\Mail` Key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.
You will find there all installed [MAPI clients][1].`.
You can also determine the default one by looking at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Clients\Mail\Default.
```

See also: [article and tool / source code to download](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1257005/How-to-find-users-email-address)

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer is no ... but of course the email address will be stored in their email program such as Outlook.

What is it you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Email addresses could be for web-based clients like gmail or they could be domain email addresses.  Either way the implementation would have to be based on the specifics of the user's email setup.  So the short answer is "no", at least there's no "one-size-fits-all" method.

Answer (score 0):

There may be SOME email address stored within Windows, but for you to get a user's actual email address, you have to have them type it in, and to assure it, you have to handshake by sending them an activate email before you use it.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but if like me you arrive here, as per this answer on Superuser

https://superuser.com/questions/836220/get-email-address-of-current-logged-in-user

On CMD run `whoami /upn`

It gives the user principal which is often the default email

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/whoami